# Surjectivity, injectivity, maps and matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to figure out when $F(x)=Ax$ (where A is an n×m matrix) is injective and surjective. $F:\mathbb R^m \to \mathbb R^n$

I believe that it is surjective when you can solve $F(x)=y$, ie when $m\ge n$

I believe that it is injective when $F(x)=F(y) \implies x=y$, I think this means $n\ge m$ ? Is that true?

Also, what conditions, if any, are required for A generally?

Answer (score 4):

The function $F$ is surjective if and only if $\operatorname{rank}(A)=n$, which is possible only when $n \leq m$.

The function $F$ is injective if and only if $\operatorname{rank}(A)=m$, which is possible only when $n \geq m$.